# Break from foreach loop in sql (dbo.sp_MsForEachDb)

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach

I have several databases with the same schema. All of the databases have a table called `Invoices`. Every invoice has a unique id because its a GUID. Sometimes I am given an invoice ID and I will like to know to what database it belongs. As a result I execute the following query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @sql = '
IF OBJECT_ID(''[?].dbo.Invoices'') IS NOT NULL   
begin
    declare @query NVARCHAR(255)
    Select @query = (Select [Id] from [?].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''XF4G-XF78-2156-7XH8'')    
    IF @query IS NOT NULL
    begin
          print ''Database = '' + ''?''             
    end
end
'
EXEC dbo.sp_MsForEachDb @sql
```

Basically `EXEC dbo.sp_MsForEachDb @sql` executes the `@sql` query replacing `?` for each of the databases. Once I enter the print statement because an invoice was found I will like to stop execution. In other words I was hoping to be able to do something like

```
begin
          print 'Database = ' + ''?''  
          return            
end
```

If I debug my query I still see that the query gets executed on all databases even though I already found the invoice.

Comment: Don't have the means to try this right now, but what about RAISERROR - that might kick you out of the loop maybe.

Comment: I did `RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1, ''Foo'');` the error was raised but execution of other queries continued.

Comment: You also look into writing your own version of sp_MSForEachDB (its not hard) or copying the existing one and tweak it to give you a get out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way to do this.

A completely inelegant way would be to close the cursor that the system procedure uses. Instead of `return` use `CLOSE hCForEachDatabase`. It would kick you out of the loop, but with an error. Like I said, a horrible way of doing it.

A more elegant way would be to continue the loop through all the databases, but without doing any of your processing once a match has been found. Assuming the user has rights to create a temp table you could do something like this...

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)

CREATE TABLE #StopProcess(STOP BIT NULL);

SET @sql = '
IF  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #StopProcess) = 0
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(''[?].dbo.Invoices'') IS NOT NULL   
    BEGIN
        declare @query NVARCHAR(255)
        Select @query = (Select [Id] from [?].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = ''XF4G-XF78-2156-7XH8'')    
        IF @query IS NOT NULL
        END
            print ''Database = '' + ''?''     
            INSERT INTO #StopProcess values (1);            
        END
    END
END'

EXEC dbo.sp_MsForEachDb @sql

DROP TABLE #StopProcess;
```

If you absolutely need to stop processing through all the databases, the only alternative I can think of is to roll your own version of `sp_MSforeachdb` and `sp_MSforeach_worker`.

Hope this helps.